# pydev console is not printing any print statements in eclipse oxygen

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, pydev

I have installed pydev in my eclipse oxygen. It was working fine. Suddenly(i did some editions) it stopped printing print statements in the eclipse console. I restarted the eclipse several times but no success. but my application works fine and I get response(twisted web application)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I overcame the issue. I added log statements, which routed console print outs to the log file.